# Trying to debug Python test cases from a file in a large project with subfolders using PyCharm

Tags: python, unit-testing, pycharm

I'm trying to use PyCharm to debug the test cases in a Python file that has relative imports to siblings like so:

```
from ..myfile import mymethod
```

`myfile` is in a subfolder of my project with an empty `__init__.py` file in its root.

Still, I get the following error when running the test:

> python /Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pycharm/utrunner.py mytestfile.py
>   ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package

I cannot add `myfile`'s folder as a content root on pycharm because it is a subfolder of an already defined root. If try, I get the following error message:

> Content entries should not intersect.

I cannot also easily modify any file or hack my way around it because this is a large project running in production and certainly any hack would be rejected in code review.

Any suggestions on how to properly fix this?

Comment: Can you show the directory tree?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting source folders in Settings (Ctrl+Alt+S). Choose Project, then Project Structure. Highlight a folder then click the Sources button on top. This will add the folder to your PYTHONPATH. (Not sure if this is what you meant by 'content root,' but version 2016.3.2 allows sub-folder sources of other sources.)